# RCP - Application does not have an active window

Tags: java, rcp, e4

What is the best way of getting non-stale EPartService/EModelService/MApplication references inside of a custom service?  I know it can be done inside a Handler via the @Execute method, but I don't see a way of doing it in a custom service class.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Singleton
@Creatable
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private EPartService partService;
    @Inject
    private EModelService modelService;
    @Inject
    private MApplication application;

    @Inject
    public MyService(final IEclipseContext context) {
        context.set(MyService.class.getName(), this);
    }

    public void doWork(){
     // Application does not have an active window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the active leaf context:

```
IEclipseContext activeContext = application.getContext().getActiveLeaf();

EPartService partService = activeContext.get(EPartService.class);
```

I don't think the model and part service actually change so just using `application.getContext()` should also be OK.

The application object does not change.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm a little confused when you say "I don't think the model and part service actually change" and "The application object does not change". Are you saying that none of those objects go stale? If so, what would be the fundamental difference between the Injects in my example code and the active leaf in your code?

Comment: For these particular services I don't think there is a difference. Some things like EHandlerService and EContextService do change so you need to use the active leaf for them. It also depends on how early in startup your service is created, if it is before the application startup is complete you may not be able to inject everything.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened because EPartService created for each window and when you annotated your service as @Singleton EPartService injected to your service only one time and when you changed window EPartService not updated. So remove annotation @Singleton and everything will be OK.